# Using GreaseKit: if a string is present in a table cell, then click a specific button IF it appears in the very same cell

Tags: javascript, if-statement, html-table, var, greasekit

I am using GreaseKit (so JavaScript)

## Step #1 Look for string & Step #2 Click button

When [this HTML page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/only-3-2-1-left-send-me-item.html) loads, if either of the following :

- `Only 3 Left` or
- `Only 2 Left` or
- `Only 1 Left`

appears in [a table cell](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/only-3-2-1-left-send-me-item.html) AND a button with `class="PrmryBtnMed"` is present **in that very same cell**, then click the button using `el.click();`

## Can we just look inside the `<tr>` tags?

If not, an alternative approach might be to just click the first button that appears immediately underneath, or after the desired string.

update: thanks to @Bergi, it seems we can just use:
`var LookInCells = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');`

## About that button: which attribute to look for?

the bit of html looks like: `<a href="/gp/wine/taste-next-123/" class="PrmryBtnMed" id = "product-B00123456"><span>Send me this item</span></a>`

So, thinking about attributes of the button

#### These will always be the same:

- `class="PrmryBtnMed"`
- `<span>Send me this item</span></a>`

#### These will always vary, so might as well ignore:

- where the link points to (e.g. `a href="/gp/wine/taste-next/"`)
- the id will always be 'id = "product-B00123456"'

Comment: You appear to have a good idea of what's to be done. What is your problem? What's not working at the moment? What code have you written, what error messages are you facing?

Comment: @DavidHedlund Hey, I'm stuck on the part about searching for a string, going about it cell by cell. Once the string is found, I want to click the button in that cell. How would I go about approaching that, using code, please? (Well, actually, the cells to be looked at will always be in [the last column](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/only-3-2-1-left-send-me-item.html) but I figure it might be easier to approach it in a generic fashion.

Comment: The other thing I'm stuck on, is, using code, how to look for the string. Should I use an array like this: ['Only 3 Left', 'Only 2 Left', 'Only 1 Left']. _Or, alternatively_, could I say look for 'Only x Left' where X is an integer that is more than zero, but less than four?

Comment: And because it's [a very large HTML document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/only-3-2-1-left-send-me-item.html) perhaps I could tell the code to only bother looking inside `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags. Maybe it's not even necessary, but it might be more elegant/efficient.

Comment: @John: You won't be "looking between tags". You have the HTML already parsed in a DOM, and you can just `document.getElementsByTagName("tr")` to get all `<tr>` elements

Comment: @Bergi okay, **thanks**, so I could start with, say `var LookInCells  = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');` ? and then use a `for` to search through each one?

Comment: @John: Yes, exactly. Of course you could start right away with a more complex selector, like `document.getQuerySelectorAll("td:last-child a.PrmryBtnMed")` and then navigate the DOM a bit differently…

Comment: @Bergi Ooh, that looks good. I shall start with that! When it comes to writing the first part of the `for`, i'm stuck. Could I use `for(var i = 0;i < LookInCells.length;i++)`

Comment: @John: Try it! (hint: yes) Maybe `console.log(LookInCells)` will also help you to get a feeling of available properties…

Comment: @Bergi Okay, I've tried to answer, on this page. Please could you take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a go at this based on the kind guidance of @Bergi!

```
var LookInCells = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var MyString =  ['Only 3 Left', 'Only 2 Left', 'Only 1 Left']
for(var i = 0;i < LookInCells.length;i++){
}

var inPage = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf(MyString) > 0,
// el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed");
el = document.getQuerySelectorAll("td:last-child a.PrmryBtnMed")    
if (inPage && el) el.click();
```